# Show hidden div element inside V-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm Beginner in Vue

i have an array list (categories and subcategories)
for example

```
<ul v-for="category in categories">
    <li class="categories" v-on:click="subcategorieshidden = false">
      {{category.name}}
      <ul class="subcategories" v-if="!subcategorieshidden" v-for="subcategory in category.subcategories">
        <li>{{subcategory.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

in this case show function working for only first category

so I need to make a dynamic function by 'this' event or function by category id

for example, if we click the second category then it must be toggle the second categories' subcategory

i can make v-on:click="showsubcat(subcategoryId)", but i dont know how to show from showsubcat function in vue

Thanks

Comment: It's recommender to not use `v-if` combined with `v-for`, instead you should use `computed` value and filter you `v-for` value.

Answer (score 0):

Since each `category` is already an object, you can make the boolean flag a property of each of those objects, skipping the need for a separate method. You said "toggle", so I suppose you want a second click to hide the subcategories again. (You also need to move the lower `v-for` down to the `<li>` where it belongs.) Here's what all that would look like:

```html
<ul v-for="category in categories">
    <li class="categories" v-on:click="category.subcategoriesHidden = !category.subcategoriesHidden">
        {{category.name}}
        <ul class="subcategories" v-if="!category.subcategoriesHidden">
            <li v-for="subcategory in category.subcategories">{{subcategory.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you want all categories' subcategories to be hidden by default, reverse the logic to have the field be `subcategoriesShown`.